# format_to_n result size type should be std::size_t instead of int

Tags: c++, c++20

I am experimenting with `std::format_to_n` and when I tried to compile example from:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format_to_n

in VS2019:

```
#include <format>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    char buffer[64];
 
    const auto result =
        std::format_to_n(buffer, std::size(buffer), 
                         "Hubble's H{0} {1} {2} km/sec/mpc.",
                         "\u2080", "\u2245", 71);
 
    std::cout << "Buffer: \"" << std::string_view{buffer, result.size} << "\"\n"
              << "Buffer size = " << std::size(buffer) << '\n'
              << "Untruncated output size = " << result.size << '\n';
}
```

it gave me the following error:

```
1>C:\Users\mike\source\repos\SoTester\SoTester\SoTester.cpp(15,7): warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u2080' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)
1>C:\Users\mike\source\repos\SoTester\SoTester\SoTester.cpp(15,17): warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u2245' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)
1>C:\Users\mike\source\repos\SoTester\SoTester\SoTester.cpp(17,64): error C2398: Element '2': conversion from 'const int' to 'const std::basic_string_view<char,std::char_traits<char>>::size_type' requires a narrowing conversion
```

I don't understand why `result.size` is of type `int`? Shouldn't it be `std::size_t`?

Now I have to either use `static_cast<std::size_t>` or resign from using uniform initialization.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Report it to Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `std::format_to_n` returns a `std::format_to_n_result<char*>`. The type of the result is defined like this:

```cpp
template<class OutputIt>
struct format_to_n_result {
    OutputIt out;
    std::iter_difference_t<OutputIt> size;
};
```

And `std::iter_difference_t<char*>` is `std::ptrdiff_t` (which is evidently the same as `int` on your system).

As for why it's `difference_type` and not just `std::size_t` is that it's possible `std::size_t` isn't big enough (imagine the OutputIterator given writes to a file and is given a 64 bit difference_type, whereas std::size_t is just 32 bit). But since you are writing to a `char*`, a cast of the size to `std::size_t` is fine.

If you want to avoid casts to `std::size_t` everywhere, you can use pointers:

```cpp
auto [end_ptr, size] = std::format_to_n(...);

std::string_view{buffer, end_ptr}
```

Comment: fmt lib makes it a lot easier by explicitly using std::size_t type: https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#_CPPv4I0EN3fmt18format_to_n_resultE